GNS3 on Debian 12
I installed gns3 on debian 12
the problem is that when I try to run gns3 it seems that there are errors with python
root@debian:~# source gns3env/bin/activate
(gns3env) root@debian:~# gns3
Fatal Python error: Aborted

Current thread 0x00007f94215b7040 (most recent call first):
  File "/root/.local/pipx/venvs/gns3-gui/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gns3/application.py", line 47 in __init__
  File "/root/.local/pipx/venvs/gns3-gui/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gns3/main.py", line 237 in main
  File "/root/.local/bin/gns3", line 8 in <module>

Extension modules: PyQt5.QtCore, PyQt5.QtGui, PyQt5.QtNetwork, PyQt5.QtWidgets, gns3.qt.QtCore, gns3.qt.QtGui, gns3.qt.QtNetwork, gns3.qt.QtWidgets, PyQt5.QtSvg, gns3.qt.QtSvg, PyQt5.QtWebSockets, gns3.qt.QtWebSockets, psutil._psutil_linux, psutil._psutil_posix (total: 14)
Abandon

please help me because I don't understand what's going on
